# Fast fourier transform for deasonalizing data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, preprocessor, filtering, signal-processing, fft

I'm very much a novice at signal processing techniques, but I am trying to apply the fast fourier transform to a daily time series to remove the seasonality present in the data. The example I am working with is from here: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/frequency-domain-linear-regression.html

While I understand how to implement the code as it is written in the example, I am having a hard time adapting it to my specific application. What I am trying to do is create a preprocessing function which deseasonalizes the training data using similar code to the above example. Then, using the same estimated coefficients from the in-sample data, deseasonalize the out-of-sample data to preserve its independence from the in-sample data. Basically, once the coefficients are estimated, I will normalize each new data point using the same coefficients. I suspect this is akin to estimating a linear trend, then removing it from the in-sample data, and then using the same linear model on unseen data to detrend it i the same manner.

Obviously, when I estimate the fourier coefficients, the vector I get out is equal to the length of the in-sample data. The out-of-sample data is comprised of much fewer observations, so directly applying them is impossible.

Is this sort of analysis possible using this technique or am I going down a dead end road? How should I approach that using the code in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is certainly possible, you are on the right track, but you seem to misunderstand a few points in the example. First, it is shown in the example that the technique is the equivalent of linear regression in the time domain, exploiting the FFT to perform in the frequency domain an operation with the same effect. Second, the trend that is removed is *not* linear, it is equal to a sum of sinusoids, which is why `FFT` is used to identify particular frequency components in a relatively tidy way.

In your case it seems you are interested in the residuals. The initial approach is therefore to proceed as in the example as follows:

(1) Perform a rough "detrending" by removing the DC component (the mean of the time-domain data)

(2) FFT and inspect the data, choose frequency channels that contain most of the signal.

You can then use those channels to generate a trend in the time domain and subtract that from the original data to obtain the residuals. You need not proceed by using `IFFT`, however. Instead you can explicitly sum over the cosine and sine components. You do this in a way similar to the last step of the example, which explains how to find the amplitudes via time-domain regression, but substituting the amplitudes obtained from the FFT.

The following code shows how you can do this:

```
tim = (time - time0)/timestep;  % <-- acquisition times for your *new* data, normalized
NFpick = [2 7 13]; % <-- channels you picked to build the detrending baseline

% Compute the trend
mu = mean(ts);
tsdft = fft(ts-mu);
Nchannels = length(ts);      % <-- size of time domain data
Mpick = 2*length(NFpick);
X(:,1:2:Mpick) = cos(2*pi*(NFpick-1)'/Nchannels*tim)';
X(:,2:2:Mpick) = sin(-2*pi*(NFpick-1)'/Nchannels*tim)';

% Generate beta vector "bet" containing scaled amplitudes from the spectrum
bet = 2*tsdft(NFpick)/Nchannels;
bet = reshape([real(bet) imag(bet)].', numel(bet)*2,1)
trend = X*bet + mu;
```

To remove the trend just do

```
detrended = dat - trend;
```

where `dat` is your new data acquired at times `tim`. Make sure you define the time origin consistently. In addition this assumes the data is *real* (not complex), as in the example linked to. You'll have to examine the code to make it work for complex data.